# Inclusion exclusion principle in set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can some one help me as i am struck in how to prove inclusion exclusion principle in set theory without using Venn diagrams

That is we have to prove:

> $|A \cup B \cup C|=|A|+|B|+|C|+|A \cap B \cap C|-|A \cap B|-|B \cap C|-|C \cap A|$.

Comment: Sketch a Venn diagram of three sets and their possible intersections, identify the terms in your expression with parts of your diagram, and you should be all set.

Comment: The Venn diagram should basically tell you what to do. Basically, the 2 set inclusion-exclusion principle tells you that by counting everything that's in each set separately, you've double counted everything that's in any two sets. So you subtract that off. But now you've "triple subtracted" whatever was in all three sets, after having double counted it, which means you've taken this piece away one too many times. So you have to add that back in.

Comment: I have mentioned in the question that i need to prove this without using Venn diagrams

Comment: Your actual proof can't use Venn diagrams, but you can use a Venn diagram to visualize the steps that you should then write out in symbols.

Comment: Are you trying to prove inclusion-exclusion for just 3 sets, or for any number of sets?

Comment: I am trying to prove for first 3 set then i will generalize that to some k sets

Answer (score 3):

Here's a derivation using indicators. Let the universe be $X$. Write $I(A)$ for the *indicator* of set $A$, i.e., $I(A)$ is the function mapping $X$ into $\{0,1\}$ such that $I(A)(x)$ takes value $1$ when $x\in A$, and $0$ otherwise. Then

$$
\begin{align}
I(A\cup B\cup C)&\stackrel{(1)}=1-I[(A\cup B\cup C)^c]\\
&\stackrel{(2)}=1-I(A^c\cap B^c\cap C^c)\\
&\stackrel{(3)}=1-I(A^c)I(B^c)I(C^c)\\
&\stackrel{(4)}=1-[1-I(A)][1-I(B)][1-I(C)]\\
&\stackrel{(5)}=I(A)+I(B)+I(C)-I(A)I(B)-I(B)I(C)-I(A)I(C)+I(A)I(B)I(C)\\
&\stackrel{(6)}=I(A)+I(B)+I(C)-I(A\cap B)-I(B\cap C)-I(A\cap C)+I(A\cap B\cap C)
\end{align}
$$
Steps (1) and (4) use the fact $I(A)=1-I(A^c)$ for the complement $A^c$ of set $A$; step (2) is set algebra; steps (3) and (6) use the fact $I(A\cap B)=I(A)I(B)$; step (5) is algebra. To obtain your result, sum over all $x$ in $X$, using $\sum_x I(A) = |A|$.

Comment: I am not able to get what is I(A)(x)

Comment: $I(A)$ is a function that represents membership in set $A$. $I(A)$ equals either zero or one. It is defined for every $x\in X$. If $x\in A$, then $I(A)$ has value $1$, otherwise if $x\not\in A$ then $I(A)$ has value $0$.

Comment: May be you r correct but if i am not able to understand and write on my own its of no use to me .So sorry

Comment: Apologies, this approach may be too advanced. Can you see how to get the result for 2 sets using this approach? If so, you can follow the approach of user84413 to get the result for 3 sets.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use the basic property for 2 sets, then

$|A\cup B\cup C|=|(A\cup B)\cup C|=|A\cup B|+|C|-|(A\cup B)\cap C|$

$\hspace{.8 in}=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|+|C|-|(A\cap C)\cup (B\cap C)|$

$\hspace{.8 in}=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|+|C|-\big(|A\cap C|+|B\cap C|-|(A\cap C)\cap(B\cap C)|\big)$

$\hspace{.8 in}=|A|+|B|+|C|-|A\cap B|-|A\cap C|-|B\cap C|+|A\cap B\cap C|$

---

Here is an alternate argument, which uses ideas similar to those in grand_chat's answer:

Take an element x in $A\cup B\cup C$, and assume that it is in exactly $k$ of these sets, where $1\le k\le 3$.

Then x is counted once by the left side, and it is counted $\binom{k}{1}-\binom{k}{2}+\binom{k}{3}$ times by the right side.

Since $\binom{k}{1}-\binom{k}{2}+\binom{k}{3}=\binom{k}{0}=1$, both sides count x the same number of times.

Comment: I don't think this is correct as for proving inclusion and exclusion principle for three sets you have used the inclusion and exclusion principle for two sets but what if i say you how you proved inclusion and exclusion principle for two sets ?

Comment: You are right -- I wasn't sure if you could use the principle for 2 sets or not, so that's why I started my solution with the wording I used.  (Proving the principle for 2 sets is straightforward, though.)